# Ajax request django rest framework

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a problem. Every time I have to clear caches and cookies first and then the AJAX request can be requested successfully. Otherwise I will get 403 response from the server, which is Django RESTful framework.
This is what I request

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url_add,
  type : 'PATCH',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'followup_customer': note,
  },
  statusCode: {
    200: function() {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Is it for an old Django version and you are testing in Chrome?

Comment: Are you using any kind of CSRF Token validation in your setup?

Comment: The django version is 2.0.6, and I did not set up anything about CSRF. Should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a correct HTTP header, containing CSRF token as described [in django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: Thank you so much!